# How to get the start time, end time in seconds from YouTube timestamp using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, extract

I'm having a list of timestamps of a YouTube video.

Example:

```
timestamps = ['0:02-0:35', '0:50-1:18', '2:53-3:08', '3:12-3:14', '3:16-3:22', '3:25-3:28', '1:09-1:35', '1:38-1:48', '2:04-2:14', '2:30-2:40', '2:45-2:50', '3:35-4:07', '4:16-4:22', '4:48-4:54', '5:00-5:12', '5:34-5:54', '8:58-9:19', '']
```

Now I need to fetch the `starttime` and `endtime` for each timestamp in `seconds` since I need to pass these as arguments for `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` method to cut a video into sub clips.

for example,

```
# If the timestamp is 0:02-0:35 The starttime and endtime should be,
timestamp = '0:02-0:35'
starttime = 2
endtime = 35

# If the timestamp is 3:02-3:35 The starttime and endtime should be,
timestamp = '3:02-3:35'
starttime = 182 # [(3 * 60) + 2]
endtime = 215 # [(3 * 60) + 35]
```

Can we do it with regex? or Is there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regex, capturing the minutes (`\d{1,2}`) and seconds(`\d{2}`) from the source string.

```py
import re
interval = '0:02-0:35'
start_min, start_sec, end_min, end_sec = map(int, re.findall('\d{1,2}', interval))
```

or split time by `:` and `-` via [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

```py
start_min, start_sec, end_min, end_sec = map(int, re.split('[:-]', interval))
```

But you can also simply do it by a built-in function [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```py
start_min, start_sec, end_min, end_sec = (int(t) for time in interval.split('-') for t in time.split(':'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. All the three were working!